Finding resistor and capacitor values for a snubber circuit to reduce diode's reverse recovery time
I'm trying to wrap my head around snubber circuits. I've read that the purpose of these circuits is to absorb energy coming from voltage spikes when a switch closes. We're currently studying snubber circuits for helping with diodes' reverse recovery. We were asked to find values for an RC snubber so that the diode's voltage never surpasses 80% of its \$V_{RRM}\$ in the following circuit:

From what I've read the most common approach for this is starting off with 2 base values for the resistor and capacitor, which are calculated as:
$$ R_{base} = \frac{V_d}{I_{RR}} $$
$$ C_{base} = L_{\sigma} \frac{(I_{RR})^2}{(V_d)^2} $$
This is all based on Ned Mohan's Power Electronics book, which is what we're using as baseline for this course.
I can't seem to understand what those values represent. I understand where do they come from, and from what I read on chapter 28 of the book it seems like \$C_{base}\$ is the capacitor value such that if \$R_s=0\$, the diode's reverse voltage is equal to the capacitor's max voltage, so I guess they "cancel out" so that the reverse recovery time is 0.
\$R_{base}\$ is the resistor value such that if \$C_S=C_{base}\$ the resulting snubber minimizes the inverse voltage as much as possible. But then I read that I might have to try different values to see which fits best, so I would think the design process of a snubber is not as straightforward as simply getting the RC values from a simple equation.
Then again, the problem asks me to find values to limit the reverse voltage to 80%, so I would think I should calculate an analogue to Cbase, but for that 80% of the voltage.
My biggest question in this matter is, what exactly do those RC values represent? Is my understanding correct?
I truly apologize for this confusing question!

You can have a look at this video by Sam Ben-Yaakov on limiting the peak reverse voltage on a boost diode at turn off. The capacitor value is determined based on the characteristic impedance of an $LC$ network: $V=I\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$ and if you extract $C$, you have your definition, while the resistance depends on the wanted $Q$ factor. This doc could also be of interest.

In that case it would be correct to assume that Cbase is the ideal capacitance value so that the max voltsge on the capacitor is equal to the maximum reverse voltage on de diode?

The $C$ value limits the peak voltage by offering a lower characteristic impedance. The $R$ damps the $RLC$ circuit and adjusts the $Q$ factor but with power dissipation in mind. In this type of design exercise, there is often a tradeoff between the benefits and dissipated power. In my opinion, it is better to dissipate a bit of power on a passive component rather than approaching a dangerous breakdown voltage on a diode.

This has clarified a lot, thank you!

Here is "some" answer (simplified) to your question on what represents the RC values.
The value of the Ls inductor fixed to 10 uH.
NB: The diode I used 1N3495 is rated to max 10 kHz, 25 A, 400 V, model of microcap v12.
I have only varied the resistor around the Rbase value (5, 10, 15 Ohm).
In black, it is the diode current (10 A forward, it can be -20 A in reverse).

One can see that for the lower value (5 Ohm), the Vd voltage is more varying than for the others.
The last graph shows the "averaged" power of this resistor. It is the "lowest" for that value.

so I would think the design process of a snubber is not as straightforward as simply getting the RC values from a simple equation.

Yes, it is not straightforward, one must choose the values "at best".

Thank you for your response. From what i can see, lower resistance values result in less power through the resistor with a tradeoff of bigger ripples, which makes sense, so the correct aprroach for this exercise would be to try out different values so that no ripple surpasses 320 V (i.e: 80% of the Vrrm) right? I guess Rbase and Cbase are nothing more than initial values for the snubber. One should calculate these and try various values to see which best fits our requirements, Am i right?

The capacity value is quite "wide". The resistance is more targeted. But you are right, the calculated values are a starting point.

Thank you! i can continue on my own from here
